# PDO Invalid parameter num

Tags: php, pdo

I have created this function to insert data into database and it does it, but it throws a warning saying:

> Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

code:

```
$first = (rand(1, 100));
$second = (rand(1, 100));
$last = $first + $second;
$stmt = $connection->prepare("
INSERT INTO equations (first_number, second_number, operation, result) 
VALUES (:first_number, :second_number, :operation, :result)
");

$stmt->bindParam(':first_number',$first, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':second_number',$second, PDO::PARAM_INT);

if ($last <= 100) {

    $stmt->bindParam(':result', $last, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':operation', "+", PDO::PARAM_STR);

} else if ($first > $second) {

    $second_result = $first - $second;
    $stmt->bindParam(':result', $second_result, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':operation', "-", PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Your condition does not guarantee that all params are bound all the time, for example: `$second=80, $first=70`, this case `:result` and `:operation` are not bound because  `$last > 100` and `$first < $second`

Comment: @catcon - possibly leave this comment as an answer - apparently the error message is cryptic enough that it led to a question, so an answer might show future users what to look for.

Answer (score 1):

If both of your conditions fail, you do not have an `else` clause, so your statement is missing 2 values. Assuming that you do not want to execute it when the values are missing I would suggest to move the execute call inside of the if statement.

```
$first = (rand(1, 100));
$second = (rand(1, 100));
$last = $first + $second;
$stmt = $connection->prepare("
    INSERT INTO equations (first_number, second_number, operation, result) 
    VALUES (:first_number, :second_number, :operation, :result)
");

$stmt->bindParam(':first_number', $first, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':second_number', $second, PDO::PARAM_INT);

if ($last <= 100) {
    $stmt->bindParam(':result', $last, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':operation', "+", PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();
} elseif ($first > $second) {
    $second_result = $first - $second;
    $stmt->bindParam(':result', $second_result, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':operation', "-", PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition does not guarantee that all params are bound all the time. 
For example:

```
$second=80; 
$first=70;
```

With this case `:result` and `:operation` are not bound because `$last` is more than 100 and `$first` is less than `$second`. I suggest edit your code to cover the rest condition:

```
if ($last <= 100) {
    $stmt->bindParam(':result', $last, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':operation', "+", PDO::PARAM_STR);
} else if ($first > $second) {
    $second_result = $first - $second;
    $stmt->bindParam(':result', $second_result, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':operation', "-", PDO::PARAM_STR);
} else {
    // this else will cover the rest
    $other_result = ... // do your magic here
    $stmt->bindParam(':result', $other_result, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':operation', "other", PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
```